# Iterar datos en tabla HTML Relación Muchos a Muchos

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo una consulta por medio de las relaciones de Eloquent que me devuelve data de una relación muchos a muchos

```
$data = Product::with('categories')->get();
```

Dentro de la vista intento iterarlos por medio de dos ciclos `foreach` para pintarlos dentro de una tabla así

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre del producto</th>
                <th>Nombre de las categorías</th>
            </tr>

       @foreach($data as $d)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $d->name }}</td>

            @foreach($d->categories as $category)

                    <td>{{ $category->title }}</td>
            @endforeach
            </tr>
       @endforeach
    </table>
```

Sin embargo me genera una tabla *descuadrada* como se ve en la siguiente imagen

Donde `design` y `frontend` también pertenecen a `JS` sin embargo no logro que queden alineados dentro de la tabla

Me generan 2 `td` dentro del mismo `table` pero como si fueran una nueva columna; la duda es como itero de manera correcta los datos para visualizarlos así

Quiero que `design` y `frontend` esten dentro del mismo `td` que `backend` en el renglón de `JS`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo te hace falta sacar la etiqueta de la celda `<td></td>` fuera del segundo buble foreach, el de `$d->categories`. He puesto un salto de línea para que no salgan pegadas, pero puedes poner un separador ' - '.

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre del producto</th>
                <th>Nombre de las categorías</th>
            </tr>

       @foreach($data as $d)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $d->name }}</td>
              <td>
            @foreach($d->categories as $category)

                    {{ $category->title }} <br>
            @endforeach
             </td>
            </tr>
       @endforeach
    </table>
```